WinUI 3 Custom Component Authoring
How can I create a Custom Control to be used in WinUI 3?
It must respond to mouse events (click, hoovering, dragging, double click)
Drawing with GDI commands (not User Control)

Can you be more specific about what you mean by "Drawing with GDI commands (not User Control)"?

Using the Graphic commands like: DrawString, DrawPath, DrawLine instead of gluing other controls

About create a custom control in winui3, I suggest you could refer to the Doc: Build XAML controls with C#

@Jeaninez-MSFT, 20 years ago I followed a walkthrough from MSFT to authoring customs controls for Windows Forms. It was well documented including graphics, event overloading, packing and testing. That walkthrough was enough to create my first custom control and still is running. Now I need to update it to WinUI3, but I can't find that kind of documentation.

If you want to use the winui3 custom control in Windows App SDK app? If so , you could create a a C# component with WinUI 3 custom control, and then consume it from a C++ Windows App SDK app. Refer to the Doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/platform/csharp-winrt/create-winrt-component-winui-cswinrt

You can create a user control, which can handle mouse events, and instead of using GDI commands you can use Win2d in it.
For example:
<UserControl
  xmlns:win2d="using:Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml" ...>
  <win2d:CanvasControl Draw="CanvasControl_Draw" />
</UserControl>

private void CanvasControl_Draw(CanvasControl sender, CanvasDrawEventArgs args)
{
    args.DrawingSession.DrawText("Hi!", 300, 300, Colors.SkyBlue);
}


Note this does not use "GDI commands" (not sure it answers the question).

@SimonMourier You are right. Added that note in my answer.

@AndrewKeepCoding Thanks for your advice but still I have question about events overloading and packing as Custom Control. But it is a good starting point quest.
